# Running time of nested while loops

Tags: while-loop, runtime, big-o

```
Function f(n)
    s = 0
    i = 1
    while i < 7n^1/2 do
        j = i
        while j > 5 do
            s = s + i -j
            j = j -2
        end
        i = 5i
    end
    return s
end f
```

I am trying to solve the running time for big theta with the code above. I have been looking all over the place for something to help me with an example, but everything is for loops or only one while loop. How would you go about this problem with nested while loops?

Comment: Can you tell how many times the inner loop will do? The outer? Then multiply. You are lucky they are independent here. And... surprise! The inner one is constant time...

Comment: Woops! I mistyped when I wrote out the function. The j was actually supposed to be equal to i...

Comment: In this case things are bit more complicated. You will have to come up with a sum of non-trivial series and see what these are converging to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this down into two key points:

- `i` starts from 1, and is self-multiplied by 5, until it is greater than or equal to `7 sqrt(n)`. This is an exponential increase with logarithmic number of steps. Thus we can change the code to the following equivalent:

  ```
  m = floor(log(5, 7n^(1/2)))
  k = 0
  while k < m do
     j = 5^k
     // ... inner loop ...
  end
  ```
- For each iteration of the outer loop, `j` starts from `i`, and decreases in steps of 2, until it is less than or equal to `5`. Note that in the first execution of the outer loop `i = 1`, and in the second `i = 5`, so the inner loop is not executed until the **third** iteration. The loop limit means that the final value of `j` is 7 if `k` is odd, and 6 if even (you can check this with pen and paper).

Combining the above steps, we arrive at:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First loop will do `7 * sqrt(n)` iterations. Exponent `1/2` is the same as `sqrt()` of a number.

Second loop will run `m - 2` times since first two values of i are 1 and 5 respectively, not passing the comparison.

`i` is getting an increment of `5i`.

Take an example where `n = 16`:

```
i = 1, n = 16;
while( i < 7 * 4; i *= 5 )
    //Do something

First value of i = 1. It runs 1 time. Inside loop will run 0 times.
Second value of i = 5. It runs 2 times. Inside loop will run 0 times.
Third value of i = 25. It runs 3 times. Inside loop will run 10 times.
Fourth value of i = 125. It stops.
```

Outer iterations are n iterations while inner iterations are m iterations, which gives O( 7sqrt(n) * (m - 2) )

IMO, is complex.

Comment: Yeah I messed up when writing out the function. The j was supposed to be equal to i so they are dependent on each another.